# Showing Iframe in a https site shows warning

Tags: iframe, https, ssl-certificate, vimeo

I have a page on my website https://www.mydomain.com/about . It consist of a vimeo video. 
We are embedding the vimeo video in a iframe on the page.

But it shows a security warning stating that "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely ?".

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning means that some content on your page was served through HTTP instead of HTTPS. It tells the user that, even though the page itself was served through HTTPS, it includes content (image, stylesheets, scripts, iframes) that was not authenticated, and that such content may be subject to MITM attacks.

If you want to avoid the warning, you should set the source of the iframe to an `https:` URL.