# iframe height change and override relative div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using wordpress 3.7.1

I have a payment page that build from main page and third party iframe.
Under the iframe there is a relative div.
My problem is that sometimes the iframe add some warnning messegase at the bottom of it and override the relative div. 
what should I do in order to make my div position will  adjusted to the Iframe?

thanks

Comment: I see only one problem here - You forgot provide the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267152/showing-iframe-in-a-https-site-shows-warning

Comment: non of these helpful.

Comment: the problem is the ifrmae height change, do not pushing down the div, and it overide it.. see pics...  [link](https://www.visa-usa.co.il/1.JPG) and [link](https://www.visa-usa.co.il/2.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just by leaving enought space between the warnning messages and the button. So when the warnning messages apear they are very close to the button.